# Creation of a database, hangs up the server for 2 minutes

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have been using the following script to create databases for a while, but recently, when I run this, it runs for good 2 minutes and slows down sql server to a halt almost.

Any ideas for to look for to diagnose this?

I do notice that while this is happening, one disk seems to be rather busy [image]

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [fbg125]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'fbg125', FILENAME = N'D:\SQLData\fbg125.mdf' , SIZE = 1048000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'fbg125_log', FILENAME = N'C:\SQLData_logs\fbg125_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1048000KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [fbg125].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [fbg125] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Comment: You don't have instant file initialization on, so SQL Server has to zero out disk space when it creates files. Even if you turn it on, the log file will still have to do this for the log file, so maybe try creating smaller log files.

Comment: thanks @sp_BlitzErik however, I create log files of the size that they grow to; i was under the impression that this is good as this creates a continues file. All thought with SSDs, I wonder if this still applies?

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily correct for any kind of disk. Best of luck!

Comment: As a test, try creating a 10mb data and 10mb log file and measure the time - your screenshot showed the drive where your mdf was being created, so that could've been the zeroing out of the mdf

Comment: If your disks are provided by a SAN or raid array, the blocks for your files won't be continuous in any case.  How do you know that's what the log file will eventually grow to be?

Comment: Continuous logfiles are not that important with SAN or SSD or Cache Controllers however the logfiles should initially not be too small initially to enable a good automatic number of logical logs. (There are all kind of 'optimal' schemes for that)

Comment: Thank you for comments everyone. I create the log file, to the max size that it will likely be. My Disks are local on the server, and SSDs. 

I've done some tests. it takes 1 minute to create a DB with 1GB log, and 30seconds for 1/2GB log file. so the time to create, seems directly proportional to the size of the log file. Also tried 1/4GB log file - 15 seconds